# Streaming large result sets with MySQL 4.1.x + Connector/J

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to get a large result set to stream and having no luck. The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) are somewhat unclear as to whether this should even work. E.g.:

> When using versions of the JDBC driver earlier than 3.2.1, and connected to server versions earlier than 5.0.3, the `setFetchSize()` method has no effect, other than to toggle result set streaming as described above.

I'm using MySQL 4.1.19 with Connector/J 5.1.6. My code is basically:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
stmt.executeQuery(“select * from huge_table”);
```

Are streaming result sets possible with MySQL 4.1.x? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "unbuffered query" in MySQL lingo, but a quick search seems to indicate that:

- MySQL only supports it starting from version 5.0
- JDBC doesn't support it